# Intermittent Failures with Celery Task Execution in Flask Application

Tags: flask, redis, celery, screen

I'm working with a Flask application that uses Celery to handle asynchronous tasks. The problem I'm experiencing is that the Celery tasks intermittently fail. The tasks work as expected about 80% of the time, but occasionally they do not execute as expected. The behavior is inconsistent, and I'm having trouble diagnosing the problem.

I've verified that the form in question is always submitted and the Flask route that processes the form is always run. I've confirmed this by logging the return parameter from the Celery task. However, the code inside the Celery task does not always execute, as the first line of the task is a logger, and I do not always see this in the logs.

Here is the Flask view that processes the form:

```
@main_blueprint.route('/process_accept', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
@login_required
def process_accept():
    # ... (omitted for brevity)
    result = run_accept_script.apply_async(args=(referral_id, python_path, script_path, comment))
    current_app.logger.info(f"Form upload parameters: {result}")
    return redirect(url_for('main.dashboard',u_id=u_id))
```

And here is the Celery task:

```
@celery.task(bind=True, default_retry_delay=5, max_retries=5)
def run_accept_script(self, referral_id, python_path, script_path, comment):
    logger.info(f'In accept celery task with referral id {referral_id}')
    try:
        # ... (omitted for brevity)
    except CalledProcessError as e:
        logger.error(f"Script failed with status {e.returncode}, retrying...")
        self.retry(exc=e)
```

It's worth mentioning that I'm running Celery inside of Screen with a concurrency of 4. There are no errors in my Redis logs.There are also no RAM issues with my server.

I'm at a loss as to why these intermittent failures are happening. Could it be an issue with Celery, Flask, or perhaps the way I've set up my tasks? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.